# How do I make my navigation item inactive again?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with my navigation bar. I am trying to make a functionality where when I click on one navigation item, it expands its children. This works perfectly. When I click on another navigation item, it collapses the previous item and expands the current one. This works perfectly, too. I have recently added a new functionality, where I want the current navigation item to keep its hovered look, making it appear active, if you guys get what i mean.

All I could come up with is this code, which indeed does some of what I want, but it doesnt make the navigation item inactive again after clicking the current navigation item, only when I click a new one. If any of this is unclear, I will provide a link.

```
$(function(){
    $(".main-nav").on("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings().find(".inner-nav").hide(); //collapse siblings
        $(this).siblings().find('a').attr('id', ''); //make siblings inactive

        $(this).find(".inner-nav").toggle(); //expand current item
        $(this).find("a").attr('id','nav-active'); //make current item active
        $(this).find("ul").find("a").attr('id',''); //remove the nav-active ID from the current items children, as it also will appear as active, which is not the desired functionality
    });
});
```

Comment: please give me the link.

Comment: looks like you are adding an ID "nav-active" but then removing it the next line. Just a guess, if you could provide a link that would be good.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mikoo1991/qyr3s0h1/embedded/result/

Comment: Martin, when you look at my code, you will see that the next line you are talking about is necessary, because it prevents the "children" from appearing active. Remove it, and you will see what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function(){
    $(".main-nav").on("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings().find(".inner-nav").hide();
        $(this).siblings().find('a').attr('id', '');

        $(this).find(".inner-nav").toggle();
        //$(this).find("a").attr('id','nav-active');
    if ($(this).find("a").attr('id') == 'nav-active') {
        $(this).find("a").attr('id','');
    } else {
        $(this).find("a").attr('id','nav-active');
    }
        $(this).find("ul").find("a").attr('id','');
    });
});
```

I added just simple verification :

```
if ($(this).find("a").attr('id') == 'nav-active') {
    $(this).find("a").attr('id','');
} else {
    $(this).find("a").attr('id','nav-active');
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r85f86e6/)

Hope, i understand you right .

Answer (score 0):

I really can't got your point very well but let me guess .. When you click on any of the children its collapse the whole div .. in this case you need `e.stopPropagation();`

```
$(function(){
    $(".main-nav").on("click",function(){
        $(".inner-nav").not($(this).find(".inner-nav")).hide();
        $(this).find(".inner-nav").toggle();
    });
    $(".main-nav > ul > li > a").on('click' , function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
      $(".main-nav > ul > li > a").not($(this)).attr('id' , '');
      $(this).attr('id' , 'nav-active');
    });
});
```

I hope this one be what you looking for

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qyr3s0h1/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you didnt solve my problem. Its not what i meant. I want the current item to appear active, and inactive upon clicking it again.